# requestAVAssetForVideo doesn't show completion block

Tags: objective-c, xcode, avfoundation, icloud, photosframework

I have this code to load a PHAsset:

```
PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:[videos objectAtIndex:index]  options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
    selectedAsset = asset;
}];
```

It works perfectly fine with videos stored on the device. But if the code should load a video from iCloud it doesn't call the completion block.
Can you help me?

Answer (score -2):

Please try additional codes 1 to 3

```
PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;

//Additional code 1
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:[videos objectAtIndex:index]  options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
    selectedAsset = asset;

//Additional code 2
dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);

}];

//Additional code 3
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```